# Ubuntu App Development. Unable to install Ubuntu SDK and buggy Ubuntu emulator

Tags: application-development, qt, ubuntu-sdk, phone

Hello I have installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 and I have no more patience to struggle with my problem. I can't install `ubuntu-sdk` package:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ubuntu-sdk : Depends: ubuntu-sdk-libs-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I really is unable to solve this problem ([unfortunately, solutions listed here don't help me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)). After my researching I understand that the next generation of Ubuntu apps will use QML language and therefore I need Qt compilers and IDE. The next step was install not Ubuntu-sdk (created on top of Qt Creator), but just Qt Creator. Thank God I installed Qt Creator from official site without any problems. But now I don't know how to use it in creating Ubuntu apps (generally speaking, I'm newbie in creating apps)

So my next step was to install `ubuntu-emulator` to see how Ubuntu Touch looks like at least. After emulator installation and instance creation I get the following:

[image]

A little excerption from terminal:

```
[    3.332876] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
[    3.352482] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0): couldn't mount as ext2 due to feature incompatibilities
                                                                            [    3.396557] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
                                                                                                            [    3.437316] initrd: boot mode: normal
                                                                                                                           [    3.510130] EXT4-fs (loop0): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
[    3.522541] EXT4-fs (loop0): couldn't mount as ext2 due to feature incompatibilities
                                                                                                                                                                                                        [    3.688075] EXT4-fs (loop0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    3.691622] initrd: mounting system.img (image developer mode)
[    3.822189] EXT4-fs (loop1): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
[    3.844501] EXT4-fs (loop1): couldn't mount as ext2 due to feature incompatibilities
                                                                             [    3.956694] EXT4-fs (loop1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    4.106987] initrd: device is generic_x86
               [    5.341856] Clocksource tsc unstable (delta = 820035903 ns)
[   12.067393] initrd: checking fstab /root/var/lib/lxc/android/rootfs/fstab* for additional mount points
                                                                       [   12.328245] initrd: checking mount label mtdblock2
                                                                                      [   12.374596] initrd: mounting /dev/mtdblock2 as /root/android//cache
mount: mounting /dev/mtdblock2 on /root/android//cache failed: Invalid argument
[   12.406983] initrd: mounting /root/var/lib/lxc/android/system.img as /root/android/system
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done.
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... done.
[   16.495823] init: ureadahead-touch main process (448) terminated with status 5
[   53.042745] init: /dev/hw_random not found
               [   53.044612] init: cannot open '/initlogo.rle'
[   53.188136] init: /dev/hw_random not found
               [   54.943603] init: cannot find '/system/etc/install-recovery.sh', disabling 'flash_recovery'
[   54.943943] init: cannot find '/system/bin/ubuntuappmanager.disabled', disabling 'ubuntuappmanager'
[   55.031468] init: property 'sys.powerctl' doesn't exist while expanding '${sys.powerctl}'
[   55.031579] init: powerctl: cannot expand '${sys.powerctl}'
[   55.031664] init: property 'sys.sysctl.extra_free_kbytes' doesn't exist while expanding '${sys.sysctl.extra_free_kbytes}'
[   55.031735] init: cannot expand '${sys.sysctl.extra_free_kbytes}' while writing to '/proc/sys/vm/extra_free_kbytes'
[   55.083456] init: cannot find '/sbin/adbd', disabling 'adbd'
[   55.094205] init: cannot find '/sbin/adbd', disabling 'adbd'
[  166.218726] systemd-logind[1013]: Failed to start unit user@32011.service: Unknown unit: user@32011.service
                                                                                                      [  166.219137] systemd-logind[1013]: Failed to start user service: Unknown unit: user@32011.service
                                                                                                                                                                                                 * Setting up X socket directories...                                [ OK ]
[  168.769983] systemd-logind[1013]: Failed to start unit user@0.service: Unknown unit: user@0.service
                                                                                              [  168.771611] systemd-logind[1013]: Failed to start user service: Unknown unit: user@0.service
                                                                                                                                                                                     * Starting automatic crash report generation: apport                [ OK ]
                                                                                                                                                                                     emulator: User configuration saved to /home/timur/.android/emulator-user.ini
```

The emulator is very slow (I work on my [HP laptop](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&dlc=en&docname=c03263474&lc=en&jumpid=reg_r1002_usen_c-001_title_r0001)) and buggy. I assume that the reason of buggy view is in video drivers and may be something relating with OpenGL, I don't know... **I will create an additional question regarding this issue**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix installing the SDK first install `ubuntu-sdk-libs-dev`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk-libs-dev
```

Then install the sdk:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
```

Comment: Thanks, now SDK installing properly! The problem now with emulators(

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. What is the issue?

There is
 1) some installation issue
 2) some issue with the emulator
 3) a bug you filed on developer.ubuntu.com (the documentation for Ubuntu App Development: https://bugs.launchpad.net/developer-ubuntu-com/+bug/1379887)

Can we disentangle the different issues into separate reports maybe?

Comment: He had a missing dependency, after this he could install the sdk, the rest should be a bug report

Comment: So I imagine it is the glitches in the emulator he is trying to solve on that bug.